# Resource.designer equivalent in IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

this may be a simple question, but I am not being able to figure it out.
This is my first time programming on ios. I have zero previous knowledge. I was asked to migrate an Android application that uses Xamarin to ios.

So far the tutorials on the internet were being very kind to me and I was able to do most of it; However, I am still not able to figure out how can I migrate the Resources.designer.cs file (the one that contains all references to the icons and animations) to ios.
I would be very grateful if you guys could tell me where can I find a tutorial for that because I was not able to find it. Most likely that due to my lack of knowledge on the platform I was not able to look for the right words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Resources.designer.cs in iOS. It's different ecosystem and there's nothing similar to Resources.designer.cs in iOS. If you are using Xamarin native and creating storyboards to create UI, I suggest that you add your images in the "Asset catalog" or the Resources folder in the iOS project. Then you can reference them in your storyboards.